# android: how to load sqlite data in hashtable

Tags: java, android, hash

I'm new to java and android. I want to get sqlite rows in a hashtable and then send them to server like a data set. I never use hash table before, as hash table takes two parameters key and value, i don't know how to pass the key can anybody tell me what is the correct way to achieve this.

```
  public Hashtable<String,ChemOrderDetailTable> getDetail(){

       db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
       Cursor c= db.query(DB_TABLE_CHEMIST_ORDERS_DETAIL, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
       Hashtable<String,ChemOrderDetailTable> hashtable = 
             new Hashtable<String,ChemOrderDetailTable>();
       if (c != null) {
             while (c.moveToNext()) {

                 String orderNo = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CHEM_ORDERS_DETAIL_ORDERNO));
                 String prodCode = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CHEM_ORDERS_DETAIL_PRODCODE));
                 String qty= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CHEM_ORDERS_DETAIL_QTY));
                 String tp= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CHEM_ORDERS_DETAIL_TYP));
                 String total = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CHEM_ORDERS_DETAIL_AMOUNT));

                 ChemOrderDetailTable chemDetailTable = new ChemOrderDetailTable();
                 chemDetailTable.setOrderNo(orderNo);
                 chemDetailTable.setProdCode(prodCode);
                 chemDetailTable.setQTY(qty);
                 chemDetailTable.setOrderNo(tp);
                 chemDetailTable.setTotal(total);

                 hashtable.put(key, chemDetailTable);

             }
          } 
     return hashtable; 

 }
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: i'm getting error on the last line because i don't know what to put for key

Comment: As you are using Collection for value ...Key can be duplicate ... so you can give any string as key ... for example String key="something"; you can decide the key value after discussing with API team too.Get the template from them.. based on their requirement you have to format and send the data to server

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked :)

Comment: Feels great to know !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sending hashtable to server

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.putAll(hashtable);
```

send `json.toString()` as a payload in API

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the default column _id as your key because they are the uniquely identifier of your rows.